# Get keys of nested TypedDicts

Tags: python, python-typing, typeddict

Having the following TypedDict:

```py
class MySubClass(TypedDict):
    name: str
    color: str

class MyClass(TypedDict):
    x: MySubClass
    y: str
```

What is the function, that can extract the keys recursively like this:

```
[x_name, x_color, y]
```

The function should be dynamic so that it can extract all kinds of nested structures, but one level of nesting is already enough.

Many Thanks!

Comment: not exactly sure what the purpose is here. `TypedDict` is only really relevant for the type checker - I haven't seen it ever being used outside of typing. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The TypedDict keys will serve as dataframe column names. In the future these keys will most likely change, and it would be easier, If the code would need to be changed only in one place, at the TypedDict structure. If inferring column names would be "automatic", adjusting column names would not be needed.

Comment: @dumbPotato21 You are correct in _most_ cases, but there are situations, where it can be useful to inspect certain typing constructs. [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/) for example accomplishes more sophisticated validation logic based on the _runtime_ analysis of `TypedDict` classes. See [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/annotated_types.py#L22) for example. So it is not _only_ relevant for static analysis. And this use case that OP mentioned in the comment of course seems legitimate too.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the more you know! Thanks for this comment and the excellent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python `>=3.10`

For Python `>=3.10` we have the [`typing.is_typeddict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.is_typeddict) function that we can use to check, if something is in fact a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) subtype.

We can use [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) (Python `>=3.9`) on a `TypedDict` class to get the keys and corresponding types defined on it. (This is likely better that using its [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48) dictionary directly as pointed out by @chepner in a comment.)

A simple recursive function to get the keys the way you wanted might look like this:

```py
from typing import is_typeddict


def get_typed_dict_keys(cls: type) -> list[str]:
    keys: list[str] = []
    for key, type_ in get_type_hints(cls).items():
        if is_typeddict(type_):
            keys.extend(
                f"{key}_{sub_key}"
                for sub_key in get_typed_dict_keys(type_)
            )
        else:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

Demo:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Foo(TypedDict):
    name: str
    color: str


class Bar(TypedDict):
    x: Foo
    y: str


class Baz(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: Bar


print(get_typed_dict_keys(Baz))
```

Output: `['a', 'b_x_name', 'b_x_color', 'b_y']`

Obviously, you might run into name collisions with the way the nested keys are formed. But I am sure you are aware of that.

**Side note**: If you are on Python **`>=3.11`** and have some keys that are annotated with [`NotRequired`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NotRequired), this solution should still work because `get_type_hints` resolves those annotations to the underlying type.

E.g. the following `Baz` class:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, NotRequired

...

class Baz(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: NotRequired[Bar]
```

The function would still work and return the same output.

---

### Python `3.9`

Here we need to get creative because `is_typeddict` is not available to us. To shamelessly steal [bits from Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/typing.py#L443), we could simply check if something is 1) a `dict` subtype and 2) has the typical `TypedDict` class attributes. This is obviously less reliable, but should work well enough in most cases:

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


def is_typeddict(cls: type) -> bool:
    if not (isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, dict)):
        return False
    return hasattr(cls, "__total__") and hasattr(cls, "__required_keys__")


def get_typed_dict_keys(cls: type) -> list[str]:
    keys: list[str] = []
    for key, type_ in get_type_hints(cls).items():
        if is_typeddict(type_):
            keys.extend(
                f"{key}_{sub_key}"
                for sub_key in get_typed_dict_keys(type_)
            )
        else:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

Same Demo, same output.

---

### Python `3.8`

Without [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), we can just use replace that call in the `get_typed_dict_keys` function with `cls.__annotations__`.

Also, the [`TypedDict.__required_keys__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict.__required_keys__) class attribute was only added in Python `3.9`, so to see if something is a `TypedDict`, we can only check for [`__total__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict.__total__). This is obviously even less robust, but the best we can do with Python `3.8`.

With type annotations etc. adjusted properly, the `3.8` code would look like this:

```py
from typing import Any, List, Type


def is_typeddict(cls: Type[Any]) -> bool:
    if not (isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, dict)):
        return False
    return hasattr(cls, "__total__")


def get_typed_dict_keys(cls: Type[Any]) -> List[str]:
    keys: List[str] = []
    for key, type_ in cls.__annotations__.items():
        if is_typeddict(type_):
            keys.extend(
                f"{key}_{sub_key}"
                for sub_key in get_typed_dict_keys(type_)
            )
        else:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

Same Demo, same output.

---

### PS, just for fun

Here is a function that can return a nested dictionary of annotations of nested `TypedDict`s and optionally flatten it, just because:

```py
from typing import Any, get_type_hints, is_typeddict


def get_typed_dict_annotations(
    cls: type,
    recursive: bool = False,
    flatten: bool = False,
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    if not recursive:
        return get_type_hints(cls)
    output: dict[str, Any] = {}
    for key, type_ in get_type_hints(cls).items():
        if not is_typeddict(type_):
            output[key] = type_
            continue
        sub_dict = get_typed_dict_annotations(
            type_,
            recursive=recursive,
            flatten=flatten,
        )
        if flatten:
            for sub_key, sub_type in sub_dict.items():
                output[f"{key}_{sub_key}"] = sub_type
        else:
            output[key] = sub_dict
    return output
```

Demo:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import TypedDict


class Foo(TypedDict):
    name: str
    color: str


class Bar(TypedDict):
    x: Foo
    y: str


class Baz(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: Bar


baz_annotations = get_typed_dict_annotations(Baz, recursive=True, flatten=True)
pprint(baz_annotations, sort_dicts=False)

print(list(baz_annotations.keys()))

baz_annotations = get_typed_dict_annotations(Baz, recursive=True)
pprint(baz_annotations, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
{'a': <class 'int'>,
 'b_x_name': <class 'str'>,
 'b_x_color': <class 'str'>,
 'b_y': <class 'str'>}
```

```
['a', 'b_x_name', 'b_x_color', 'b_y']
```

```
{'a': <class 'int'>,
 'b': {'x': {'name': <class 'str'>, 'color': <class 'str'>},
       'y': <class 'str'>}}
```

Comment: I would use `typing.get_type_hints` instead of accessing `cls.__annotations__` directly.

Comment: @chepner Good point. I always forget about that. I edited my post. While I was at it, I also added an alternative for `3.9`, when `is_typeddict` is not available.

Comment: Ironically, I think you called me out for doing something explicit instead of using `typing.get_args` or `typing.get_origin` once :) (Somebody did, anyway, which is why I remember about the `typing.get_*` functions now.)

Comment: Hi @DaniilFajnberg! Many Thanks for your detailed answer. Using Python 3.8.0b1 and your 3.8 version of the get_typed_dict_keys function I get ['a', 'b']. Any idea why?

Comment: also with Python 3.8.10

Comment: @bayerb Yes, my bad. The `__required_keys__` attribute was added in 3.9, so that check returned `False` and could not identify anything as a `TypedDict`. I fixed it in my answer and included the full 3.8 code.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! What can I do, if b within Baz is not required. Like this
class Baz(TypedDict): a: int; b: NotRequired[Bar]?

Comment: @bayerb If you use `typing.get_type_hints` to loop over the key-type-pairs (I forgot to fix that in the `>=3.10` version after chepner's comment), it will resolve `NotRequired[Bar]` to just `Bar`. So the code should still work. And since `NotRequired` is only available since `3.11`, there should be no problem.